# self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex: not working

Tags: ios6, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

Things in the project:
a storyboard which contains just one Tab Bar Controller and four view controllers (so I have four tab bar items, and four segues, very very simple)
a custom Obj-Class which is used by the Tab Bar Controller, and draw a button on the "self.view"

What's the problem:
want to simulate "pressing the tab bar item" but not it is not working. help please. (I have not any other custom-obj-class but the only one for the UITabBarController)
What I've tried:

```
[(UITabBarController*)self.navigationController.topViewController setSelectedIndex:3];

[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3];


[self.tabBarController setSelectedController
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedViewController:[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3]];
```

custom-obj-class.m :

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{    
    if (self.tabBarController) {
        NSLog(@"I have a tab bar");
        [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"I don't have"); // I GOT THIS ONE
    }
    return;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
...
    UIBarButtonItem *realRoomItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:realRoomImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:)];
...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, there's a big mistake. It should be "self" but not "self.tabBarController" since my custom-obj-class is the class of UITabBarController and used in it also.